# Permissions required to create vpc links aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, api-gateway

I am trying to create vpc links for connecting api gateway with my ec2 instance. I have created Network Load balancer. And now trying to create VPC Links in api gateway. But while creating that it throws an error as:

```
VPC link creation failed
User does not have sufficient permissions to create VPC endpoint services.
```

what all permissions I will need to create VPC Links?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions required to create `VPCLink` are detailed in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/grant-permissions-to-create-vpclink.html) and they can be encapsulated in the following IAM policy:

```
{  
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "ec2:CreateVpcEndpointServiceConfiguration",
            "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
            "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointServicePermissions"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {  
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I have policy with these details. But I am not sure how to attach this to my account!

Comment: @user11823877 You must attach it to your IAM user under which you login to the AWS console. Alternatively, you have to create IAM role with these permission which you can assume.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above accepted answer, I also needed the following, as based on the [API Gateway Management docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonapigatewaymanagement.html):

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/vpclinks/*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/vpclinks"
    ]
}
```

(Obviously I'm **us-east-1** specific in my example!)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).